# batch script to check url status without ping command

Tags: batch-file, url, ping, status, windows-server

I can't use ping command because it is blocked on my server.

I followed the anser from https://superuser.com/questions/1172790/bat-file-to-check-servers-are-up/1173006#answer-1173006. But it uses ping command in batch file.

Here is my code:

```
REM add urls in urls.txt
for /f %%a in (C:\Job-Batches\server_check\urls.txt) do (
echo Pinging %%a ...
ping -n 2 %%a | find "Reply" > NUL  
if not errorlevel 1 (   
    REM ip is down
    echo %%a is down
) else (
    REM ip is up
    echo %%a is up
)
)
```

Can someone suggest, if it can be done without ping...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should we guess at what the format of the urls are?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Windows 10 has `curl`.

Comment: @Squashman, there is only one url for now (i.e www.example.com). One more point, I need to run the batch file as a windows scheduled job on the same server. I mean the file will run on the same server where application exists..

Comment: @SomethingDark, I am using Windows server 2016.